# select div but not inputs within div jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to select a div for a click event but not the inputs within said div. I thought this would do it but it does not work. here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/t66f06oL/). Thank you

**html**

```
<div id = "test"><input></div>
```

**js**

```
$('#test:not(input)').click(function(){
    alert();
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could check to see if the clicked element is an `input` element using `!$(e.target).is('input')`

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/9dy9etao/)

```
$('#test').on('click', function (e) {
    var $target = $(e.target);

    if (!$target.is('input')) {
        alert('clicked');
    }
});
```

Comment: a good work-around, but is there not a way to select only non-inputs?

Comment: @user2014429 Well you would have to use `$('#test :not(input)')`. http://jsfiddle.net/ejvmhe6o/

Comment: this seems the simplest way to do it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you click on the input, the click event bubbles to the div above it.

You can stop this by calling `stopPropagation` or `stopImmediatePropagation` on the event object.

http://jsfiddle.net/t66f06oL/1/

```
$( '#test' ).on( 'click', function() {
   alert();
} );

$( '#test' ).on( 'click', 'input', function( e ) {
   e.stopImmediatePropagation();
} );
```

Answer (score 1):

When you click on the `input` control your `click` event is actually caught by the parent div. You can fix this by changing your code to this:

```
$('#test:not(input)').click(function(){
    alert();
});

$('#test').find('input').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```